# New QGIS 3.16 error - UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa9'

Tags: qgis-3, unicodeencodeerror

For some reason this error now occurs when I open a project in QGIS 3.16. The best I can find online is that the folder path referenced in the error should not contain spaces.

Unfortunately it is not possible to rename the folder that has a space in its name - "Application Support".

There have been no changes made, so why would this error suddenly appear?

WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/username/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis-maptiler-plugin/maptiler.py", line 172, in _write_copyright_entries
print(trimed_copyrights_text)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Unfortunately there are no basemaps in the projects

Comment: The error is caused by the maptiler plugin. In the file maptiler.py, in the method _write_copyright_entries, line 172: `print(trimed_copyrights_text)`. I guess it is something to do with non ascii character in the attribution string of a layer in your project.

Comment: Actually could be any layer! Try unchecking layers to see if you can work out which one. Or if you are not using the plugin just uninstall or un-enable it.

Comment: Uninstalling the plugin has eradicated the error! Good thing I have been using XYZ Tiles for basemap layers. Thank you so much, these random out of the blue errors are quite lame. Much appreciated.

Comment: Bugs in plugin code are part of life! Developers cannot always foresee or test for every edge case. I would also suggest to see if you have the latest version of the plugin and if not- upgrade; maybe the bug is already fixed (although I suspect not since the line number in the code repository matches the line number in your error). If you wanted to, you could report the bug to the developers at the plugin's github repository issues page: https://github.com/maptiler/qgis-maptiler-plugin/issues

Comment: During this I did find an update available, applied it and the problem persisted. It’s fine, like I mentioned I haven’t used Maptiler so no big deal. It is just odd to make no changes then come back to an error that stops operations for seemingly no reason. Good idea to let the developers know.